# LightFM model: scores and sigmoid function inside

Tags: python, machine-learning, cython, lightfm

I have two questions related to the LightFM model:

1. I read the [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.08439.pdf)%C3%A5%C2%AF%C2%B9%C3%A4%C2%BA%C5%BD%C3%A5%C2%AD%C2%A6%C3%A6%C5%93%C2%AF%C3%A8%C2%AF%C2%BB%C3%A8%E2%82%AC%E2%80%A6%C3%A6%20%C2%A5%C3%A8%C2%AF%C2%B4%C3%A4%C2%BF%C2%A1%C3%A6%20%C2%AF%C3%A9%E2%80%A1%20%C3%A5%C2%BE%CB%86%C3%A5%C2%A4%C2%A7%C3%AF%C2%BC%C5%92%C3%A4%C2%BD%E2%80%A0%C3%A6%CB%9C%C2%AF%C3%A5%C2%AF%C2%B9%C3%A4%C2%BA%C5%BD%C3%A4%C2%B8%20%C3%A5%C2%A4%C2%AA%C3%A7%E2%80%A0%C5%B8%C3%A6%E2%80%9A%E2%80%B0%C3%A8%C2%BF%E2%84%A2%C3%A4%C2%B8%C2%AA%C3%A9%C2%A2%E2%80%A0%C3%A5%C5%B8%C5%B8%C3%A7%C5%A1%E2%80%9E%C3%A4%C2%BA%C2%BA%C3%A6%20%C2%A5%C3%A8%C2%AF%C2%B4%C3%A5%20%C2%AF%C3%A8%C6%92%C2%BD%C3%A6%C5%93%E2%80%B0%C3%A7%E2%80%9A%C2%B9%C3%A7%C2%AE%E2%82%AC%C3%A7%E2%80%A2%C2%A5%C3%A3%E2%82%AC%E2%80%9A%C3%A6%CB%86%E2%80%98%C3%A5%C2%B0%E2%80%A0%C3%A5%C5%93%C2%A8%C3%A4%C2%B8%E2%80%B9%C3%A9%20%C2%A2%C3%A6%E2%80%BA%C2%B4%C3%A7%C2%AE%E2%82%AC%C3%A5%20%E2%80%A2%C3%A5%C5%93%C2%B0%C3%A6%C2%A6%E2%80%9A%C3%A8%C2%BF%C2%B0LightFM%C3%A6%C2%A8%C2%A1%C3%A5%C5%BE%E2%80%B9%C3%A7%C5%A1%E2%80%9E%C3%A9%C2%A2%E2%80%9E%C3%A6%C2%B5%E2%80%B9%C3%A7%C5%A1%E2%80%9E%C3%A8%C2%BF%E2%80%A1%C3%A7%C2%A8%E2%80%B9) about the model and I see that it uses sigmoid f(.)-function. I also checked library's [Cython code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lyst/lightfm/master/lightfm/_lightfm_fast_no_openmp.c) and I see that the function is implemented there as well. However, the model is applicable to rank items in the rating setting (rating from 1 to 5). Why isn't sigmoid harming the ranking system? I mean it returns the value from 0 to 1, why the model still works for ratings?
2. Am I correct that the scores which model returns is q_u * p_i + b_u + b_i (see the article)? If not, how can I calculate the scores myself? Where do they come from and why their magnitude is so high? I get the scores approximately from -100000 to +100000.

UPD1: I followed the comments and found out the following function:

```
cdef inline flt compute_prediction_from_repr(flt *user_repr,
                                             flt *item_repr,
                                             int no_components) nogil:

    cdef int i
    cdef flt result

    # Biases
    result = user_repr[no_components] + item_repr[no_components]

    # Latent factor dot product
    for i in range(no_components):
        result += user_repr[i] * item_repr[i]

    return result
```

It seems like the scores are indeed the formula above, but it would be helpful if someone could also have a look - I'm not very good with Cython

UPD2: sigmoid is used only for the logistic variant of the model. It's not used if you try WARP.

Comment: I use WARP-loss in my model and I see that the scores change with the parameters, so it seems reasonable that WARP changes them with gradient steps. However, I still don't understand why we don't have any problems with sigmoid and how scores relate to the formula.

Comment: I didn't get it too, but since it's using the sigmoid function as an objective function, then, all F(x) must be in the range [0, 1]. Can we suppose that the author is multiplying the scores by 5 since it will give values within the range [0, 5]?

Comment: You almost certainly want to be looking at the pyx code that goes into Cython rather than the c code that comes out. It'll be much much more readable

Comment: @DavidW here is pyx code https://github.com/lyst/lightfm/blob/master/lightfm/_lightfm_fast.pyx.template I'm still not sure about both questions(

Answer (score 0):

The model works for ratings using Sigmoid because LightFM **binarizes** the recommendation problem.

For ratings between 1 to 5 with 5 being the highest,

- ratings 4 and 5 indicate user interest in the item -> Positive
- ratings from 1 to 3 indicate user not interested in the item -> Negative

This is the reason model performance is indicated using a **AUC score**.
For an individual user, AUC corresponds to the probability that a randomly chosen positive item will be ranked higher than a randomly chosen negative item.

In my case I applied the **WARP** Loss and use WARP score as an indicator to closeness of the item to the user in feature space to being liked by the User. For a probabilistic score or ratings prediction other sophisticated models may be considered.